# How does this forward-sexp-function in hs-special-mode-alist work?

Tags: hideshow

I wanted to look up the different `hs-special-mode-alist` `forward-sexp` functions for inspiration to create my own and this is what the `python` `forward-sexp` looks like on my setup:

```
;; (MODE START END COMMENT-START FORWARD-SEXP-FUNC ADJUST-BEG-FUNC)

((python-mode "^\\s-*\\(?:def\\|class\\)\\>" nil "#"
  #[257 "\300 \207"
                    [python-nav-end-of-defun]
  2 "\n\n(fn ARG)"]
 nil)
```

The thing that starts with `#[257 "\300 \207"` and ends with `ARG"]` is supposed to be a function for moving forward with `forward-sexp`. What the h is it showing? Is that valid elisp? Is it compiled code? Just gibberish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#[...]` is *byte code*, which comes from byte-compiling the Lisp source code.

You need to use `C-h f` for the Python `forward-sexp` command, and then visit its Lisp definition (by clicking the file link) to see what it does.

If you don't know what the Python `forward-sexp` function is called, use `C-h k C-M-f` in Python mode. (That will also give you a link to the source code.)